# Add fragment under existing views

Tags: android, view, fragment, admob

I have a fragmentActivity that contains an AdView view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativePrincipal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="**********" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This FragmentActivity will contains several fragments, and i would show AdView inside each fragments. There's a way to put fragments "under" AdView, or i need to add AdView for each fragment i'll use inside FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's a way to put fragments "under" AdView ... ?

Of course, you can do it like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="**********" />

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativePrincipal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/banner" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: of course, it was simple :) i need to sleep a little bit! thanks

Comment: that's sure ! don't forget to accept the answer. Happy that helped you ;)